# Help on how to solve this question involving tangent circles and semicircles

Tags: geometry, circles

[image: The Problem]

Hi,

I gave a link to the problem. I’ve tried multiple times to solve it but can’t. Can someone provide help please?

Edit: In case it wasn’t clear , I’m referring to the top question

Comment: Hint: By [Descartes's circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_theorem),
$$\left(\frac1r + \frac11 + \frac12 - \frac13\right)^2 = 2\left(\frac1{r^2}+\frac1{1^2}+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}\right)^2 \implies r = \cdots$$

Comment: I found a proof of Descartes' circle theorem here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/descartes-theorem/ I was wondering (1) is there an easier proof of Descartes' circle theorem? And (2) is there a way to solve this problem without Descartes' circle theorem?

Comment: This is the first circle of a [Pappus chain](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappusChain.html).

Comment: See also here: http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/GeometryConicSectionPappusChain.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is the radius of the circle with center $P$, then: 
$$AP=2+x,\quad BP=1+x,\quad CP=3-x.$$ 
If $H$ is the projection of $P$ on $AB$, we can also set: 
$$PH=h,\quad AH=a,\quad BH=3-a,\quad CH=a-1.$$ 
From Pythagoras' theorem applied to triangles $APH$, $BPH$, $CPH$ you can then obtain three equations in the three unknowns $x$, $h$, $a$, which can be easily solved.

[image]